# Putting dataset in CV

Tags: citations, cv, doi

In my field (linguistics) sometimes datasets are important and scholars tend to include them in their CV. I want to know how to include my dataset in my CV?

This is the approach I have in mind: Uploading dataset in [Harvard Dataverse](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/) and include the DoI in CV with the following style:

```
XXX dataset, The most important dataset in linguistics, DOI:XXXXXXXXXX
```

How does it look? Please share your thoughts on it.

Comment: If you're given a DOI for the dataset, definitely include it. I agree with Bill below that authors are advisable - treat it as you would a paper citation. Harvard appear to have a standard citation form for their datasets which looks reasonable.

Comment: So what is the most important data set in linguistics?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt it is a comical name given to hypothetical dataset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Harvard Dataset users guide:

> Download Citation
>
> You can find the citation for the dataset at the top of the dataset
>   page in a blue box. Additionally, there is a Download Citation button
>   that offers the option to download the citation as EndNote XML or RIS
>   Format.

So if you go that route just upload your data and click that button.

Answer (score 6):

It seems pretty presumptuous to call it the most important dataset in your field. If it's got a DOI, then you can leave off the editorial. Just give the title and the DOI. An author list might be appropriate if there is a consistent set of authors. If the dataset is continuously evolving or growing, you might leave the authors off. This may depend on the conventions of your field. Also, if there's a marker paper that describes the first use of that dataset, and you're an author on that paper, you should also put that on your CV.

Comment: Actually "the most important dataset in linguistics" was a comical description given to a hypothetical dataset. Actually I don't have a DOI for the dataset but the paper (which is submitted) has DOI; however the dataset can be used in different researches (and therefore cited) so I was thinking about mentioning Harvard Dataset's DOI in description. Having said that can the aforementioned style be any good?

Comment: Do you think it would have been better to provide a real example of what you were planning to put as the citation?

Comment: For example I am developing the first Kurdish Speech Corpus for training HMM Text-to-speech. this endeavour (training a software for TTS) solely can be considered as a Research output and published. The corpus on the other hand can be used in other areas for different purposes so I'm thinking about uploading the corpus in the Harvard dataverse so that others can easily Download, Cite, and Reuse my data. and also I can easily put the DOI in my CV so that the admission committee of the universities I'm applying to can easily find my work.

Comment: @adelrahimi, finding a way to get permanent hosting and a DOI would be ideal. No matter what, cite it in your CV, but not in the "Peer-Reviewed Publications" section. Make a new section for it, like "Research Procucts".

Comment: @BillBarth I cite them under the heading:CODES AND PROJECTS 
thanks for your help.

Comment: @adelrahimi, that sounds like a fine heading.

Answer (score 3):

We don't generally subdivide CV entries according to the usual P&T requirements, though if you're in a sub-area that's more remote within linguistics, like computational, then there might be different standards. The standard format of the entry in an academic CV would be:

2015a. Kurdish speech corpus. http://hdl.handle.net/1234.5/678910, Harvard Dataverse, V1

or if co-authored, with the added tag ("w. Y. Matras & G. Haig", or whatever is appropriate). (You can also deposit it at [TROLLING](http://opendata.uit.no/dvn/dv/trolling)).

Comment: Thanks for your great reply I actually got the idea after receiving the announcement for TROLLING.

Answer (score -2):

If the job you are applying for requires dataset creation, then list one of your skills as "dataset creation" and in the text next to it explain that you created the Harvard Linguistic Dataset. If the dataset is important in the field you are applying to, you need only name it. If the reader of your CV doesn't know the dataset is important, it's perhaps not worth even mentioning.

Comment: I'm applying to grad schools and the people reading my CV are scholars from my field. 
Of course the dataset is important in our field and mentioning it alone is enough; however by mentioning DOI I want to 1. give a clear address where they can thoroughly and easily (I can upload it in my personal website for example but giving a URL can never be as short as a DOI) see my research data  and 2. they can cite, see and download my data.

Comment: _If the dataset is important in the field you are applying to, you need only name it._ — Strongly disagree.  This is like saying "If the paper is important in the field you're applying to, the title is enough." Like any other artifact, if you cite a dataset (either in your CV or in a paper), you **must** give proper credit to all co-creators, and you **must** provide enough information for a novice user to find it (DOI and/or persistent URL).

Comment: In my experience, academic CVs, unlike those for industry, don't usually have a "skills" section. And in a field that uses data, listing "dataset creation" as a  skill would be about as silly as listing "writing papers" - every applicant must have this skill, so what's the point of writing it? You might as well list "breathing".